# JWPlayer implemention without JWPlayer SDK for Native android app?

Tags: android, webview, jwplayer

is it possible to use **JWPlayer** for android native app without JWPlayer SDK? i mean is there any workaround to stream video stored in my server with  JWPlayer. As per my understanding there is no possibility but would like to confirm and if there is any possibility please share related tutorial or code.

thanks.

Comment: it is like you want to write java program and execute it without using JVM. is that possible?

Comment: so your question seems incorrect, modify your question.

Comment: without SDK? which SDK are you asking about? you mean Android SDK or JWPlayer SDK?

Comment: There is an Android SDK for using the player in a native Android App. http://www.jwplayer.com/android-sdk/

Comment: Assuming the question is how to use JWPlayer in Android w/o JW Android SDK the answer would be: you can embed JWPlayer for web in Android WebView. Obviously the experience would not be nice/smooth compared to JW Android SDK. ;)

Comment: thanks @maxmikheyenko but can you share any code or tutorial for implementing JWPlayer using webview as you told?

Comment: @Florida are you using our SDK? You need to contact us directly to get information about this (http://www.jwplayer.com/products/mobile-sdk/)

Comment: @Florida I don't have any code for that, but I know it's possible - i've seen it a number of times. Sorry guys, you're on your own here.